# How to check instant buffer cache size in oracle database with ASMM?

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to make a piechart that shows `SGA` components such as java pool,large pool etc. One of the components is buffer cache.

I could check all parameters in `sgainfo` view, for example:

```
SQL> select * from v$sgainfo
  2  ;

NAME                                  BYTES RES
-------------------------------- ---------- ---
Fixed SGA Size                      2261448 No
Redo Buffers                      226615296 No
Buffer Cache Size                3.3957E+10 Yes
Shared Pool Size                 3623878656 Yes
Large Pool Size                   671088640 Yes
Java Pool Size                    671088640 Yes
Streams Pool Size                         0 Yes
Shared IO Pool Size                       0 Yes
Granule Size                      134217728 No
Maximum SGA Size                 3.9152E+10 No
Startup overhead in Shared Pool  2780532240 No

NAME                                  BYTES RES
-------------------------------- ---------- ---
Free SGA Memory Available                 0

12 rows selected.
```

But the problem is, i'm working on a database that has ASMM(Automatic Shared Memory Management) which means SGA size is automatically controlled(so it's components values are changing). So i need instant values of this components. I can get java,shared and large pool's values from `sgastat` view, but not buffer cache's value.

Comment: maybe I'm wrong, but wouldn't v$sgainfo give you the (dynamic) value you want?  (v$ views aren't static).

Comment: No, sgainfo stores static variables. dynamic values are stored in sgastat.

Comment: really?  As far as I know, v$ views are "dynamic performance views", and are, well, dynamic.  That same value in v$sgainfo can be found in another v$ view v$sga_dynamic_components (that ones even got the "dynamic" in the name), and this view's "current_size" should be the same as v$sgainfo.  It also shows the "last_oper_time" and "last_oper_type" showing recent changes to the values.

Comment: Take a look at:  V$MEMORY_DYNAMIC_COMPONENTS
.
.Just curious - what are you trying to accomplish?  Why are you doing this?

Comment: I'm developing a monitoring program.

Answer (score 1):

`SQL> col BYTES for 99999999999999999999999
SQL> select * from v$sgainfo;`

```
NAME                                                BYTES RES
-------------------------------- ------------------------ ---
Fixed SGA Size                                    2545736 No
Redo Buffers                                     69644288 No
Buffer Cache Size                            429765165056 Yes
Shared Pool Size                              64424509440 Yes
Large Pool Size                                 268435456 Yes
Java Pool Size                                  201326592 Yes
Streams Pool Size                               268435456 Yes
Shared IO Pool Size                                     0 Yes
Granule Size                                     67108864 No
Maximum SGA Size                             495000064000 No
Startup overhead in Shared Pool               25433410328 No
Free SGA Memory Available                               0

12 rows selected.
```